# Could not find artifact while dependency is in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I'm getting following message when I try to build my maven project: 
Could not find artifact com.sap.cds:cds-feature-mt:pom:1.4.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

These are my parent and child module:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>customer</groupId>
<artifactId>CAP-parent</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>CAP parent</name>

<properties>
    <!-- OUR VERSION -->
    <revision>1.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>

    <!-- DEPENDENCIES VERSION -->
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <cds.services.version>1.4.0</cds.services.version>
    <cds4j.version>1.8.0</cds4j.version>
    <spring.boot.version>2.2.5.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>

    <node.version>v12.16.1</node.version>
    <node.url>https://nodejs.org/dist/</node.url>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>srv</module>
</modules>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- CDS SERVICES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cds</groupId>
            <artifactId>cds-services-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${cds.services.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cds</groupId>
            <artifactId>cds-starter-cloudfoundry</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- SPRING BOOT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- STEPS TO GENERATE CDS ARTIFACTS WITH AVAILABLE NODE/NPM -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>cds build</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>run</argument>
                                <argument>build</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>cds schema</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>run</argument>
                                <argument>schema</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- STEPS TO GENERATE CDS ARTIFACTS WITH EIRSLETT -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-node-and-npm</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <downloadRoot>${node.url}</downloadRoot>
                            <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>cds build</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>cds schema</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run schema</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <!-- JAVA VERSION -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- MAKE SPRING BOOT PLUGIN RUNNABLE FROM ROOT -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- POM FLATTENING FOR CI FRIENDLY VERSIONS -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <updatePomFile>true</updatePomFile>
                <flattenMode>resolveCiFriendliesOnly</flattenMode>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>flatten</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>flatten</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>flatten.clean</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- PROJECT STRUCTURE CHECKS -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Project Structure Checks</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireMavenVersion>
                                <version>3.5</version>
                            </requireMavenVersion>
                            <requireJavaVersion>
                                <version>${jdk.version}</version>
                            </requireJavaVersion>
                            <requireProperty>
                                <property>project.artifactId</property>
                                <regex>[^_]+</regex>
                                <regexMessage>"The artifactId should not contain underscores
                                    (_) as this causes issues when deploying to Cloud Foundry."</regexMessage>
                            </requireProperty>
                            <reactorModuleConvergence />
                        </rules>
                        <fail>true</fail>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <artifactId>CAP-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>customer</groupId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>CAP</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>CAP</name>

<!-- ACTUAL DEPENDENCIES -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sap.cds</groupId>
        <artifactId>cds-starter-spring-boot-odata</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sap.cds</groupId>
        <artifactId>cds-starter-cloudfoundry</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <!-- SPRING BOOT PLUGIN -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>repackage</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- CONFIGURE ADDITIONAL SOURCE DIRECTORY FOR GENERATED CLASSES -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/gen/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- GENERATE POJO INTERFACES -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.sap.cds</groupId>
            <artifactId>cds4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cds4j.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <csnFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/edmx/csn.json</csnFile>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/gen</outputDirectory>
                <basePackage>cds.gen</basePackage>
                <eventContext>true</eventContext>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>localized.*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>cds4j-generate-model</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- CLEAN GENERATED ARTIFACTS -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/gen</directory>
                        <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                    </fileset>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>edmx/**</include>
                            <include>schema.sql</include>
                        </includes>
                        <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <!-- A profile that uses global installation of @sap/cds-dk -->
    <profile>
        <id>cdsdk-global</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <!-- STEPS TO GENERATE CDS ARTIFACTS IMPORTED FROM PARENT -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/..</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <!-- The default profile that uses eirslett plugin to install and perform cds commands -->
    <profile>
        <id>cdsdk-local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <!-- STEPS TO GENERATE CDS ARTIFACTS IMPORTED FROM PARENT -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

In my second dependency it contains the dependency cds-starter-cloudfoundry which should containcom.sap.cds:cds-feature-mt:pom:1.4.0 is there something wrong?

Comment: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.sap.cds%20AND%20a:cds-feature-mt will give you only one result: version 1.5.1

Comment: https://answers.sap.com/questions/12998298/could-not-find-artifact-comsapcdscds-feature-mt.html